# Salesforce Streaming / CometD Scaling

Tags: streaming-api, cometd

Since CometD is a client / server implementation, i.e. messages flow directly from SalesForce into subscribed clients, I'm wondering what options there might be regarding horizontal scaling of the consumers. As I understand it, if there are 5 clients subscribed to a given topic they will all get the same messages. Unless there's a way of splitting the SalesForce topic among several clients working together similar to the way Kafka consumer groups do - is there anything in SalesForce Streaming / CometD that would allow this?

Comment: For passing message to specific users in salesforce you can use https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/generic_streaming_intro.htm.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's not quite what I was looking for though. I'm looking for something that would allow me to configure a group of clients as 'one' so that they share the messages consumed from a single SalesForce topic. Like I said, I'm struggling to see how that would be possible though given the nature of CometD

Comment: So if you have 10 clients and each has registered to same message bus (Platform Event) from salesforce, you want each clients to get the same message, right?

Comment: Not quite - if I have 10 clients, I want to be able to load balance the messages from a given SalesForce topic between all of them - not to each of them.

Comment: salesforce streaming events works like a message bus, it does not have load balancing feature. For that you can create a middle layer , in JAVA or any other language, using EMP connector  (JAVA) and then connect KAFKA or RABBITMQ and then balance it from there.

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought too. In my case, the middle layer would be Kafka Connect. So based on that, it's my understanding that there's little point in having more than one worker since they wouldn't be able to load balance the SalesForce topic. That's where I was coming from